# Is it possible to round robin DNS requests?

Tags: dns, bind, dnsmasq

I'm not sure I've phrased this appropriately, but what I'm trying to accomplish is an ever so slight annonymization of the machines online footprint by issuing DNS queries to a list of DNS servers in a round robin format, rather than continuing to use the same service over and over because it answered the fastest.

I've got `dnsmasq` set up on my CentOS system and queries are being routed through it as expected.  `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` is as follows...

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
log-queries
user=dns
group=dns

listen-address=127.0.0.1

server=1.1.1.1
server=1.0.0.1
server=208.67.222.222
server=208.67.220.220
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

So at the moment, I can see in my log that upon a DNS query request, dnsmasq is issuing the query to *ALL 6* of the services at once...

```
dnsmasq[5801]: query[A] example.com from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 8.8.4.4
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 8.8.8.8 
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 208.67.220.220 
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 208.67.222.222
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 1.0.0.1 
dnsmasq[5801]: forwarded example.com to 1.1.1.1
```

...and returning the first response.

What I would like is that it only issue the query to the first server, and return/cache the response unless there's an error. If there's an error, it should move to the next server in the list until it gets a proper response.  Then the next query for a new request should go to the next server in the list..... like a round-robin.

Is that possible?

Comment: Technically that's just 3 services with two addresses each... If you're going to do this for privacy reasons, it doesn't help to include duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with dnsmasq or bind. There might be other DNS services that perform some load balancing.

If I had to do this, I would look at a load balancer, or 'traffic manager' service to receive the DNS request, and then round-robin it to multiple dnsmasq resolvers (either in docker containers or running on different ports). That way I can configure each dnsmasq service to use one of those forwarders.

But the actual load balancing has to be done be a different service.

Comment: It might also be possible to write some "interesting" iptables firewall rules to intercept DNS queries and route them randomishly using the "statistics" module and minimal overhead.

Comment: I did exactly what @davidgo suggested - using iptables DNAT rules with "statistic" module (round-robin fashion) to load balancing dns queries to a bunch of dnsmasq docker workers. Full script can be found here:  https://github.com/L3w1s-L1u/roundrobin-dnsmasq

Comment: Nginx with an algorithm based load balancing strategy would be much better. However it   requires nginx+ which can load balance UDP streams but is a charged feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no problem with using something other than `dnsmasq` or `bind` you might want to try `coredns` which has `policy round_robin` in its `forward` plugin:

> - **policy** specifies the policy to use for selecting upstream servers. The default is **random**.
>
>   - **random** is a policy that implements random upstream selection.
>   - **round_robin** is a policy that selects hosts based on round robin ordering.
>   - **sequential** is a policy that selects hosts based on sequential ordering.

(from https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/)

davidgo's comment is interesting too, but you have to watch out for the [pseudo-]connection tracking that can happen automatically, to avoid sending a whole bunch of requests to the first IP address chosen in whatever manner.

Answer (score 1):

A solution follow @madacoda 's idea:

Using iptables as load balancer to receive DNS request from default 53 port, then dispatch requests (DNAT) to different ports listened by dockerized dnsmasqs.

This requires serveral iptables DNAT rules and "statistic" module. Say you have 3 resolver and you'd like to load balance among them. The iptables rules would be like:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d <listen_address> -m udp \
--dport 53 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every <N> --packet 0 \
-j DNAT --to-destination <listen_address>:<resolver_listen_port(N)>

sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -o lo -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW \
-m statistic --mode nth --every <N> --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination \
 <listen_address>:<resolver_listen_port(N)>
```

where N=1,2,3 and "listen address" is used to receive all DNS queries. "resolver_listen_port" would be like "5301,5302,5303" in this case.

Since local queries don't go through PREROUTING chain, the second rule in above example is applied to allow local queries also be load balanced among resolvers.

Using statistic module with "nth" mode will dispatch query streams among backend resolvers in a round-robin fashion, though I think it's not the best way to handle DNS requests.  Using Nginx as a load balancer will give a more rational balancing scheme but unfortunately to handle UDP stream would require Nginx Plus, which is a non-free feature.